# Trying to compress an image of 1658 by 1156 to a div of width : 800px; height:100%; as a background image

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to use an image of 1658 by 1156 as a background image to a div of width 800px and height 100%. My target is to compress down the image to the size of the width using css but the image still overlaps the size of the div. This is my attempt:

```
<div  style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width : 800px; height:100%" class="col-md-8 col-xs-8 col-lg-8">  

                    <div class="panel panel-body" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: fixed; background-position: center; overflow-scroll: none; width : 800px; height:100%;z-index: 1;  padding:2px; border: black solid thin;background: url(resources/img/bck.JPG) center top">
```

Please how can I compress the image down to the size of the div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `background-size: cover`

```
<div class="panel panel-body" style="background-image: url('http://www.soar-nj.com/media/k2/galleries/1176/fhpeqpl5.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: fixed; background-position: center; width : 800px; height:100%; z-index: 1;  padding:2px; border: black solid thin; background-size: cover; ">
```

Solution without cropping the image (Using `background-size: 100% 100%;`).

It will span the image to 100% width and 100% height but that will stretch the image since image is larger than the container. So, I would recommend that you use `background-size: cover` or use an image with less resolution.

```
<div class="panel panel-body" style="background-image: url('http://www.soar-nj.com/media/k2/galleries/1176/fhpeqpl5.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; width : 800px; height:100%; z-index: 1;  padding:2px; border: black solid thin; background-size: 100% 100%; ">
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/8Qax3CxojJI0d8Z3ORyx?p=preview)

That will scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image.

Comment: Can you please provide a demo through fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/ that shows your problem clearly so that I can solve it.

Comment: Have tried creating a plunk demo but dont know how to attach a background image to it

Comment: Thanks for the demo. You will have to add the image with absolute path. I have added an image from google with the dimensions you mentioned. And edited the answer and demo. Have a look if that's what you want

Comment: You can see that not all the image is shown. My challenge is to make all the image show within the div

Comment: If you look carefully, you will see that the image is truncated and this is how it appear in mine

Comment: The image is larger than the container. If you do not want anything to get cropped then it can be done by setting background-size: 100% 100%; but that way the image will get stretched. Which is not ideal so I would recommend that you use an image of 800px dimension or else use background-size:cover

Comment: Please how can I set background size of 100%

Comment: background-size: 100% 100%; will set the image to take 100% width and 100% height of container. But it will create stretching for your image because image is of width 1658px and container 800px.

Comment: Show me the demo of the background size 100%

Comment: The image is not full visible from your demo

Comment: It is fully scaled. That's what background-size:100% 100% does. I guess you are not scrolling. Scroll right to see the full image.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the height of your DIV to 557px and then use `background-size:cover`

OR

You can use `background-size: 100% 100%` and apply `overflow:hidden` to your DIV.